# How to rename files in VB.NET to have a unique suffix?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I understand how to rename a file in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) as I use in the code at the end of my post. However, I was wondering if it's possible to rename a file and if the file exists then to rename it and add +1 to the file name?

So if I ran the code.

'Run it first time

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("c:\test\test.txt", "c:\test\NewName.txt")
```

'Run it again, but it should add +1 as the file will already exists, so it should be "c:\test\NewName1.txt"

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("c:\test\test.txt", "c:\test\NewName.txt")
```

Update

I decided rather than rename and +1, it would be better to just date stamp it, so for anyone who struggles as I did:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("c:\test\test.txt", "Test" & Format(Date.Now, "ddMMyy") & ".txt")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write your own logic for this.

The [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class has many useful method for dealing with files.

```
If File.Exists(filePath) Then
  ' Give a new name
Else
  ' Use existing name
End If
```

The [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class has many methods for dealing with file paths.

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
If System.IO.File.Exists("c:\test\NewName.txt") Then
   ' add +1 or loop exists with increment on the end until file doesn't exist
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I cant add coding so please see first post.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to rename a file is to use the Move() method of System.IO.File.

Example:

```
System.IO.File.Move("C:\temp\file1.txt", "C:\temp\file1_renamed.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mention the complete file path in `newFileName` parameter, just mention new file name here otherwise you will get `ArgumentException`.

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\fingerprint1"

If File.Exists(filePath) Then

    Dim strNewFileName As String = "Fingerprint221"

    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(filePath, strNewFileName)

 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Public Sub RenameFile(ByRef FileFind As String, ByRef NewReplaceFileName As String)
        Dim Ada As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileFind)
        'VS2013 Dim Ada As String = File.Exists(FileFind)
        If Ada.Length > 0 Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(FileFind, NewReplaceFileName)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox("File doesn't exists")
        End If
    End Sub
```