# Rename a file extension in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've written a data sorter which writes out a .build extension to the files it's writing to so nothing tries to lift it as it's writing data to particular files.

At the end, I want to rename anything with a .build extension to a .dat before the program closes.

```
 For Each f In outputFiles

        For Each r In TrailerRecords

            ' Set the bill count variable
            If r.VariableField Then
                r.Fields(1) = String.Format("{0:000000}", f.Value)
            End If

            ' Write the trailer record to the output file
            File.AppendAllText(f.Key, r.ToString() & vbLf)
        Next

        ' Rename all.build files to .dat

NEEDS TO GO HERE

        ' Copy each output file to the backup directory
        File.Copy(f.Key, Path.Combine(backupFolder, Path.GetFileName(f.Key)), True)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784613/how-to-rename-file-in-vb-net ? It looks like it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the files and rename it:

```
Dim auxFile as String
Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(myFolderPath, "*.build")

For Each sFile As String In files
    auxFile = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFile) & ".dat"
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(sFile, auxFile)
Next
```

You can use `File.Copy()` with the overwrite property to `True` instead.

Take a look at the MSDN documentation:

- [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [RenameFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamefile%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [GetFilenameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Many Thanks SysDragon, this was just what i needed, had to play with it a bit to find the correct position in the application but i got these.

Comment: If `sFile` contains a path use:
`auxFile = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sFile), IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFile) & ".dat")`