# Rename all files

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm making a small application in Visual Basic using Studio 2015, and I'd like to know how I can rename all the files in the desktop to test1.txt, test2.txt and so on. I know already how to find the current user desktop directory, but I have no idea how to rename all files from there. Thanks!

Comment: rename all of the files into the same name? I guess something is missing in your question.

Comment: [**To get all the files in directory**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457525/get-a-list-of-all-files-inside-of-a-directory-in-vb-net) and [**To rename a file**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784613/how-to-rename-file-in-vb-net)

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the internet on how to rename files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Directory.Getfiles` you can get all files in a specific folder (in your case your desktop).

All you have todo now is to rename each file in your array.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Test.txt", "SecondTest.txt")
```

You can realize that with a `for each` that iterates though your array of files of your desktop. The name test{i} can be also build with the `for each`.